# Is it true that if a human lived long enough (up to 3-400 years), he/she would eventually develop cancer?

Tags: human-biology, genetics

I have just studied DNA, but I am not so clear. So, I would like you to explain it more clearly.

This is what I think when a human grow older and older, his or her DNA repair mechanism would be weaker and weaker and eventually so weak that it couldn't repair the DNA damages and he or she would develop cancer sooner or later?

**Is it true that if a human lived long enough (up to 3-400 years), he/she would eventually develop cancer?**

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, questions should not be speculative — such questions lead to opinion based answers and are off-topic for this site. ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

Every year we have a risk of cancer.  With enough rolls of the dice they will come up snake eyes.

That said, https://www.cancerresearchuk.org/health-professional/cancer-statistics/incidence/age#collapseZero highlights an interesting issue.  The incidence of cancer increases greatly from birth to seventies, then decreases.  If you are being optimistic enough to suppose a treatment could make you live for 400 years, I suppose you could assume your appearance and cancer risk would remain comparable to that of a teenager for hundreds of years as well.  If your cancer incidence is 0.2% per year (200 of 100,000 on the chart, 25-29 year olds) then your risk by the time 400 years have passed will be a little over 50%.